# Parsing Youtube links automatically

Tags: php, youtube

```
$message = preg_replace("#(http://(www.)?youtube.com)?/(v/|watch\?v\=)([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?#i", "<iframe title=\"YouTube\" width=\"480\" height=\"390\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$4\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", $message);
```

This works fine if youtube link looks like this:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DhSwsbKJQ4

but there is a problem if Youtube link looks like this:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DhSwsbKJQ4&feature=topvideos_music

The result is iframe and text `feature=topvideos_music` after iframe. Is there any way how to remove everything after `&` in Youtube link?

Comment: Please, note that I need to parse all Youtube links in a text. This tex may contain many youtube links.

Answer (score 3):

Why won't you use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/function.parse-url) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/function.parse-str) functions? It's a much safer solution.

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DhSwsbKJQ4&feature=topvideos_music';
// $url = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/9DhSwsbKJQ4?feature=topvideos_music';

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parsedUrl['query'], $parsedQueryString);

// URL in ?v=... form
if (isset($parsedQueryString['v'])) {
    $id = $parsedQueryString['v'];
}
// URL in /v/... form
else if (substr($parsedUrl['path'], 0, 3) == '/v/') {
    $id = substr($parsedUrl['path'], 3);
}
// invalid form
else {
    throw new ...;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off decomposing the URL with parse_url()/parse_str(), then rebuilding it from the ground up.

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/....';

$url_parts = parse_url($url);

$query_parts = parse_str($parts['query']);

$v = $query_parts['v'];

$new_url = $url_parts['scheme']; // http
$new_url .= '://';
$new_url .= $url_parts['host']; // www.youtube.com
$new_url .= '/';
$new_url .= $url_parts['path']; // /
$new_url .= '?'
$new_url .= 'v' . $v; // v=....
```

While parseing with regex will work, at some point it'll turn around and bite you. This is a bit more tedious, but safer in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

**Regular Expressions**

I am by no means a regex-pert, but the following removes the ampersand and everything following:

```
$vidpath = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DhSwsbKJQ4&feature=topvideos_music';
echo preg_replace('/&.+/', '', $vidpath);
```

Produces `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DhSwsbKJQ4`.

**Blow it to Pieces!**

The other option is to use `explode()` and split the string based on the occurences of `&`, resulting in an array where the `0` index contains your desired output.

```
echo array_shift( explode( '&', $vidpath ) );
```

In this case, `array_shift()` will return whatever item is at index `0`, which will be your path.

Comment: I like "regex-pert," but this answer won't handle the case of http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=topvideos_music&v=9DhSwsbKJQ4

use parse_url() and parse_str() from other answers instead

Answer (score 1):

Short version.

```
$url = 'url_text';
$vidparser = parse_url($url);
parse_str($vidparser[query], $query);
$video_id = ($query['v']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Try using this code before your one:

```
$message = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DhSwsbKJQ4&feature=topvideos_music';
$message = explode( '&' , $message);
$message = $message[0];
```

Now, the `$message` variable is set to `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DhSwsbKJQ4`.

Comment: This won't handle the case of http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=topvideos_music&v=9DhSwsbKJQ4

use parse_url() and parse_str() from other answers instead

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the the videoID i suggest switchting to a regex like this:

```
/(http\:\/\/(www\.)?youtube\.com)\/watch\?v=([^&]+)/ism
```

Tested it on [regextester.com](http://www.regextester.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try [pathinfo()](http://php.net/function.pathinfo)

edit after comment: try executing this:

```
<?php
$url='http://www.site.com/foo/bar.php?dummy=param&dummy2=param2';
$array=pathinfo($url);
?><pre><?php print_r($array); ?></pre>
<?php
$params=strrchr($array['extension'],'?');
$params=str_replace('?','',$params);
$params_array=explode('&',$params);
foreach ($params_array as $each) {
$eacharray=explode('=',$each);
echo $eacharray[0]; //key
echo '<br />';
echo $eacharray[1]; //value
echo '<br />';
}
?>
```

the output will be:

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => http://www.site.com/foo
    [basename] => bar.php?dummy=param&dummy2=param2
    [extension] => php?dummy=param&dummy2=param2
)
dummy
param
dummy2
param2
```

Not a perfect example, but you can get all keys/values via this method.

edit2: sorry, I was in a hurry, re editing my postt for exactly what you need.

```
<?php
//code partially taken from php.net
$character='&';
$string='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asd123&feature=related&dummytext=true';
$whole_length = strlen($string); 
$right_length = (strlen(strstr($string, $character)) - 1); 
$left_length = ($whole_length - $right_length - 1); 

$piece = substr($string, 0, ($left_length));

echo $piece; //http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asd123

?>
```

Comment: Can you provide a usage example to accompany your link?

Comment: Sorry, I was just getting out of office when I was editing, reedited my post, I think now it shoudl work. I am not deleting the old code so it may be an example for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could, as mentioned previously, first get everything up to the &, or you could simply do the following (only typing the regex for convinence).

```
#(http://(www.)?youtube.com)?/(v/|watch\?v\=)([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)#i
```

in order to make it more generic, you could do the following:

```
#(:?(:?(:?www\.)?youtube\.(:?[^/]{2,5})/(:?v/|watch\?v\=))|(:?youtu.be/))([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)#
```

The regex doesn't need to match everything. All the **:?** wich are to avoid the preg_replace to keep the reference, and by doing this it should match shortened URLs aswell. In this case, the reference would be stored in `$1`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. I get the same result - "&feature=topvideos_music" after iframe.

Comment: after testing a bit more, i found that `#(?:(?:(?:www\.)?youtube\.(?:[^/]{2,5})/(?:v/|watch\?v\=))|(?:youtu.be/))([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*#` works.
I had to fix the :? (the correct syntax is **?:**